# Display child window on the screen where the parent window is located

Tags: c++, mfc, childwindow

C++
I have a modal child window that can be launched form a main window. The application runs on a Citrix server and when the user is on dual monitors, she can drag the child window to the secondary display and somehow Windows saves this position. When she moves to a workstation with a single display, she complains that the application is freezing when in reality the child window is off the screen and can be brought to the main display with some key combinations. Is there a way I can programmatically force the child window to always open on the screen where the parent window is located?

Comment: Technically, the second window is an owned window, not a child window, though the terminology is often conflated.  A child window can only be drawn within the client area of its parent.

Answer (score 2):

You can try calling [`CWnd::CenterWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1a3x359y%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which will just position the window in the centre of the main monitor (usually above the parent window).

Answer (score 0):

You should override [PreCreateWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yc5skce.aspx) and modify the the respective entries in the [CREATESTRUCT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9930zz74.aspx) to force the window into the visible area. Guidelines for positioning a window can be found at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162827.aspx) ("Positioning Objects on Multiple Display Monitors").